# Using a different form of authentication for a subsite

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint-2010

I have a web application that runs off the domain: `test.com` using Windows Authentication.  I want to create a subsite using the domain `test.com/helloworld` but I want this subsite to have a different type of authentication.  Is it possible to create a new webapp as a subsite or just have the subsite use a different form of authentication?

Comment: are you now talking about Forms Authentication..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. We do it the other way around (Forms authentication on the outer site, windows authentication on the inner site.

The trick to making this work is in the main site, you will want to include your primary system.web configuration in a non-inheritable location tag.

For example:

```
  <location inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.web>
      <authentication mode="Windows"/>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```

then, in your sub site, you add a web.config that defines the settings for that site:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <authentication mode="Forms"/>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Comment: is the `inheritInChildApplications` needed in this case, since the subsite's web.config is going to override the authentication type, or do the two conflict with each other without it? just curious

Comment: @AnthonyShaw: We found that it was needed in our case, but that could have been because other elements in the main site's web.config conflicted with the sub app. It's a little fuzzy now.

Comment: oh ok, cool. I was just curious because I'm writing an application right now that may have to support dual authentication methods, definitely starring this question

Comment: Do SharePoint subsites have a physical web.config file? Web.config files are only per web application right?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest, extending the web application; creating an alternate access mapping and re-routing the subsite url to the new web application.

This should be smoother.